# About boot sector(s), MBR etc (Windows)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, mbr

I had a disk that boots with Win-7. On the same computer I installed another hard disk that boots with Win-10.

So now when I launch Windows, I have the choice between Win-7 and Win-10, ok.

Now that I setup Win-10 correctly, installed software, transfered my data from the Win-7 disk, I want to delete the Win-7 disk content, completely wiping it, to use for something else.

Can I do a full format of the Win-7 disk, deleting all partitions etc? In this case, will the computer correctly boots directly on Win-10? The point is that I don't know where the Windows launcher (when I am offered to select between Win-7 and Win-10) gets the information from. Is it from a special area on the Win-7 disk? Or what?

Comment: Try this: Boot in Win-10 and in an elevated cmd enter `bcdboot X:\windows /s X:`, where X is the drive letter of Win-10. Then take out the Win-7 disk and connect instead the Win-10 disk and boot. Important: Before manipulating disks, take good backups.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Harrymc, but I am a bit afraid of doing this :)

I am thinking like this:

In the Disk management program, there is a partition that is marked "System". Isn't it the partition I am looking for? It is located on the Win-7 disk, that is logical as I installed it first.

I apologize as I did not explain all more exactly, so here is a precision: This Win-7 disk is a SSD disk and my plan in fact is to move Win-10 (currently installed on a usual HD) at the Win-7 place.

So couldn't I simply clone the current Win-10 partition to the current Win-7 one? Then delete the "Win-7"entry in the boot system using msconfig?

Comment: You can reply to comments on your questions by clicking the "add a comment" link. Please don't post "answers" that are not answers to the question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should edit your original post to add additional information.